# Spring with Reactive Cassandra throws AllNodesFailedException exception and the service fails to start

Tags: java, spring, cassandra

I have built a Spring reactive application trying to connect to Cassandra. My code snippets are as follows:

**Solution 1: Reactive Cassandra [Not Working]**

Maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra-reactive</artifactId>
            <version>3.0</version>
</dependency>
```

application.yml file:

```
spring.data.cassandra.contact-points=<my connection points>
spring.data.cassandra.username=abc
spring.data.cassandra.password=xyz
spring.data.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
spring.data.cassandra.keyspace-name=mykeyspace
spring.data.cassandra.port=9042
```

Configuration:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories
public class LocalBeanConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return "mykeyspace";
    }
```

Table Class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("test_table")
public class TableClass {
    @Getter
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column("id")
    private String id;
    @Column("value")
    @Getter
    private String value;
}
```

Repository class:

```
@Repository
public interface TestAppRepository extends ReactiveCassandraRepository<TableClass, String> {

}
```

Finally I am accessing Cassandra as follows:

```
public class MyService {
   private final TestAppRepository testRepository;

   public void get(CrawlTask crawlTask) {
        testRepository.findById("id_1").map(testAppConfig -> test1(testAppConfig)).switchIfEmpty(Mono.just(test2()));
    }
}
```

Irrespective of this, I am unable to connect to reactive Cassandra and get the following exception on start up:

```
Caused by: com.datastax.oss.driver.api.core.AllNodesFailedException
```

On the contrary, if I use Spring Cassandra instead of Reactive Cassandra, I am able to connect. My code snippets for the working solution are as follows:

**Solution 2: Non-Reactive Cassandra [Working]**

Maven:

```
<dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-cassandra</artifactId>
        </dependency>
```

application.yml

```
spring.cassandra.contact-points=<my connection points>
spring.cassandra.username=abc
spring.cassandra.password=xyz
spring.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
spring.cassandra.keyspace-name=mykeyspace
spring.cassandra.port=9042
```

Table class:

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@Table("test_table")
public class TableClass {
    @Getter
    @PrimaryKey
    @Column("id")
    private String id;
    @Column("value")
    @Getter
    private String value;
}
```

Repository:

```
public interface TestAppRepository extends CassandraRepository<TableClass, String> {

}
```

Finally I am accessing Cassandra as follows:

```
public class MyService {
   private final TestAppRepository testRepository;

   public void get(CrawlTask crawlTask) {
        Mono.just(testRepository.findById("id_1").map(testAppConfig -> test1(testAppConfig)).orElse(test2()));
    }
}
```

In this way I am able to access the Cassandra table without a problem.

Now the major difference I see between the two solutions, solution 1 [not working] and solution 2 [working] is the way the Cassandra configs are being defined.

In the non-reactive case we use `spring.cassandra` and in the reactive case we use `spring.data.cassandra`.

I have also tried writing configs using `spring.cassandra` with the reactive case. Here the service starts up, but while getting data from the table, it fails to get any data. [inside MyService]

I am not sure why the non-reactive solution works but the reactive one does not. What am I missing here? Can someone kindly help me out?

***Edit 1:***

As requested, sharing the complete Cassandra stack trace + error log:

```
 s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Reactive Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 65 ms. Found 1 Reactive Cassandra repository interfaces.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data Cassandra repositories in DEFAULT mode.
.s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 4 ms. Found 0 Cassandra repository interfaces.

c.d.o.d.i.core.DefaultMavenCoordinates   : DataStax Java driver for Apache Cassandra(R) (com.datastax.oss:java-driver-core) version 4.15.0
c.d.oss.driver.internal.core.time.Clock  : Using native clock for microsecond precision
c.d.o.d.i.c.control.ControlConnection    : [s0] Error connecting to Node(endPoint=/127.0.0.1:9042, hostId=null, hashCode=3f2701f1), trying next node (ConnectionInitException: [s0|control|connecting...] Protocol initialization request, step 1 (OPTIONS): failed to send request
```

Comment: Can you please post the full error message + full stack trace? Cheers!

Comment: @ErickRamirez I have posted the Cassandra stack trace + the error log as an edit in the description above. Kindly do let me know if there is something more you are looking for.

Comment: @ErickRamirez how to I pass Cassandra username and password to the class extended by AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration in Spring 3.*? As I see getAuthProvider() has been deprecated in this version. My guess is this might be causing the error. I found a ```Authentication error (AuthenticationException: Authentication error on node``` exception.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Managed to solve this problem. The solution is as follows:

Since I am on reactive version 3.0, the Cassandra details must be mentioned as follows:

```
spring.cassandra.contact-points=<my connection points>
spring.cassandra.username=abc
spring.cassandra.password=xyz
spring.cassandra.local-datacenter=datacenter1
spring.cassandra.keyspace-name=mykeyspace
spring.cassandra.port=9042
spring.cassandra.schema-action=NONE
```

More importantly we require a @Configuration class defined as follows:

```
@Configuration
@EnableReactiveCassandraRepositories
public class CassandraConfig extends AbstractReactiveCassandraConfiguration {
    @Value("${spring.cassandra.contact-points}")
    private String contactPoints;

    @Value("${spring.cassandra.local-datacenter}")
    private String localDatacenter;
    
    @Value("${spring.cassandra.port}")
    private int port;
    
    @Value("${spring.cassandra.keyspace-name}")
    private String keySpace;
    
    @Value("${spring.cassandra.username}")
    private String username;
    
    @Value("${spring.cassandra.password}")
    private String password;

    @Value("${spring.cassandra.schema-action}")
    private SchemaAction schemaAction;

    @Override
    protected String getContactPoints() {
        return contactPoints;
    }

    @Override
    protected int getPort() {
        return port;
    }

    @Override
    public SchemaAction getSchemaAction() {
        return schemaAction;
    }

    @Override
    protected String getKeyspaceName() {
        return keySpace;
    }

    @Bean
    @Override
    public CqlSessionFactoryBean cassandraSession() {
        CqlSessionFactoryBean cqlSessionFactoryBean = new CqlSessionFactoryBean();
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setUsername(username);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPassword(password);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setKeyspaceName(keySpace);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setLocalDatacenter(localDatacenter);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setPort(port);
        cqlSessionFactoryBean.setContactPoints(contactPoints);
        return cqlSessionFactoryBean;
    }
}
```

Comment: Nice!  Glad you figured it out!